# Google charts - Drill up

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I was able to get drill down functionality using google charts api working. So basically in my view class, I have javascript which loads the google charts library and draws a pie chart.
On that pie chart selection handler, i do an Ajax call which generates a datatable and draw another chart for me.

I could not figure out how to implement a drill up using google charts. Basically I want to get the drill up functionality as same as HighCharts provide, I cannot use highcharts as it is licensed.

Can someone post some examples or ideas on how to get drill up working using google charts ?Basically i want a button to the top right corner of my level 2 pie chart and when i click that button it should take me to level 1 pie chart.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: The Visualization API won't provide that functionality, but you can add a button to your HTML and attach and event handler to the button that redraws the original chart.

Comment: Thanks David. I cannot post my code here. As asgallant mentioned if google charts api does not provide any inbuilt functionality then i'd have to go with creating a button..I will give that a try.